# Do nested IF statements not work as I would expect them to?

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a MYSQL query to update the database after adding a new column to the Oportunitati table but the nested ifs don't work like I would expect them. The query is:

```
UPDATE Oportunitati SET Stadiu = 
if(Probabilitate < '20', '1', 
if(Probabilitate < '40', '2', 
if(Probabilitate < '60', '3', 
if(Probabilitate < '80', '4', 
if(Probabilitate < '100', '5', 
if(Probabilitate = '100', '6', '7'))))))
```

I would expect this query to set Stadiu to 1 if Probabilitate is between 0 and 20, to 2 if it's between 20 and 40, etc. and finally 6 if it's 100 and 7 if it's over

However, even tho I have values in all the brackets, the only values this query sets are 1 and 7. Is there anything about nested IFs in mysql that i'm missing?

Comment: Why are all the numbers wrapped in apostrophes?

Comment: Just a habit that stuck with me since highschool. Don't think it makes a difference here.

Comment: You should quit that habit. Numbers aren't strings.

Comment: Wow that was indeed the case. It would seem I do indeed have to quit this habit.

Answer (score 1):

using of `case` instead of nested `if` is preferable in such cases:

```
UPDATE Oportunitati SET Stadiu = 
CASE
                   WHEN Probabilitate < 20
                                   THEN 1
                   WHEN Probabilitate < 40
                                   THEN 2
                   WHEN Probabilitate < 60
                                   THEN 3
                   WHEN Probabilitate < 80
                                   THEN 4
                   WHEN Probabilitate < 100
                                   THEN 5
                   WHEN Probabilitate = 100
                                   THEN 6
                   ELSE 7
END
```

Comment: Thanks, will consider it. The problem was actually my bad habit of sticking '' around every value in mysql. Thanks crappy highschool prof.

Comment: don't worry mysql casts type for you

Comment: Dunno, removing those ''s fixed it, so that must have been it.

Comment: such behavior is strange for me because `SELECT 1+'1';` -> 2

Comment: what type of `Probabilitate`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query too -

```
UPDATE
  Oportunitati
SET
  Stadiu = IF(Probabilitate <= 100, Probabilitate DIV 20 + 1, 7);
```

If you have negative `Probabilitate` then add one more condition -

```
IF(Probabilitate <= 100, IF(Probabilitate < 0, 0, Probabilitate) DIV 20 + 1, 7)
```